# How do I complete Challenge 1-10?

Tags: pushmo

I have tried this level ten times, and I can't seem to figure it out. How do I complete the level and save the Pushmo child at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

1. Pull the bottom left blue piece and the pink piece as far as possible
2. Climb the pink piece on the right and pull the blue piece as far as possible
3. Push the pink piece one space and use the left blue piece to climb on top of it
4. Stand on right blue piece and side-pull the pink piece (you'll have to stand on the far spot on the blue piece)
5. Pull the wide blue piece as far as possible, then stand on it pull the pink piece on top of it

Comment: Oh, so you don't have to use the white piece at all. Awesome!

Comment: yes. many levels have unused blocks while others require each and every block