# How do I beat level 10 in the tutorial?

Tags: pushmo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I complete Challenge 1-10?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/how-do-i-complete-challenge-1-10)

I can't seem to beat level 10 of the tutorial. I've tried many times, but haven't found a solution that works.

Comment: I was about to say, I feel like I've done this before...

Comment: @agent86 déjà vu! But I do feel validated that I wasn't the only person struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Push the right split block all the way in, go in and side push the left split block all the way out, this will allow you to drag the top blocks out further.